# Subroutine Prototype in PERL

Tags: perl

```
sub joins($ @);
print "\nEnter a letter \n\n";
$l = <STDIN>;
chomp $l;
print "\n Enter Five String \n\n";
@arr;

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    $arr[$i] = <STDIN>;
    chomp $arr[$i];
}  
@ar = joins($l, @arr);
print "\nCombined Stirng is :-  @ar\n";
sub joins {
    ($x, @str)=@_;
    @j = ($x, @str);
    return @j;
}
```

I am getting prototype mismatch error. How can i fix it ?

Comment: Do... not... use... prototypes

Comment: your code doesn't take advantage of prototypes, so don't use them

Comment: You do not need to use a subroutine to add elements to an array, those functions are built-in. See `pop`, `push`, `shift`, `unshift`. In assignment, even less so: `@ar = ($l, @arr)`

Comment: You have serious scoping errors. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, In fact, what you need to do is to change the joins function definition.
You can change "sub joins" to "sub joins($@) to agree with the declare of the joins function. The code is list like the below.

```
1 #!/usr/bin/perl
2 use strict;
3 use warnings;
4
5 sub joins($@);
6
7 print "\nEnter a letter \n\n";
8 my $l=<STDIN>;
9 chomp $l;
10 print "\n Enter Five String \n\n";
11 our @arr;
12
13 for(my $i=0;$i<5;$i++)
14 {
15     $arr[$i]=<STDIN>;
16     chomp $arr[$i];
17 }
18
19 my @ar=joins($l,@arr);
20 print "\nCombined Stirng is :-  @ar\n";
21
22 sub joins($@)
23 {
24     my ($x, @str)=@_;
25     my @j=($x,@str);
26     return @j;
27 }
```

well, by the way, you can read the documentation here about prototype(http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes). Besides, I also recommend you to use strict and warnings, although in demo code.

Comment: You forgot to add the most crucial piece of information: Prototypes do not do what you think they do, so don't use them.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you've predeclared `joins` with a prototype of `$@`, then implemented it without any prototype. As others have noted, you don't take advantage of the prototype. You also don't take advantage of the sub being predeclared (ability to call without parenthesis) so remove this line:

```
sub joins($ @);
```

On the subject of prototypes, Perl::Critic considers them to be a severity 5 (worst) violation:

> [Contrary to common belief, subroutine prototypes do not enable compile-time checks for proper arguments. Don't use them.](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/Subroutines/ProhibitSubroutinePrototypes.pm)